# Can I simplify the following vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $\boldsymbol{a}$ and   $\boldsymbol{b}$ be $n \times 1$ vectors and $M_1, M_2, ..., M_n$ be $n\times n$ matrices.

Is there a way to write the following vector:
\begin{equation}
v = \begin{bmatrix}
a^T M_1 b
\\
a^T M_2 b
\\
\vdots
\\
a^T M_n b
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

in such a way that reads $v = a^T M_{new} b$, where $M_{new}$ is just a manipulation of the $M_i$ matrices?

I know I can do:
\begin{equation}
v = \begin{bmatrix}
a^T M_1 
\\
a^T M_2 
\\
\vdots
\\
a^T M_n 
\end{bmatrix}
b
\end{equation}

But then I cannot get the vector $a$ "out of the brackets".

Comment: I think if you let $$A^T=a^T \oplus \dots \oplus a^T\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n^2}$$ $$M=M_1\oplus \dots \oplus M_n\in \mathbb{R}^{n^2\times n^2}$$ $$B=b\oplus \dots \oplus b\in \mathbb{R}^{n^2\times n}$$ then your vector equals $A^TMB$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write
$$
v = \pmatrix{a^T \\& \ddots & \\&&a^T} \pmatrix{M_1\\ \vdots \\ M_n}b.
$$
If you like, you could write the matrix on the left compactly using the fact that
$$
\pmatrix{a^T \\& \ddots & \\&&a^T} = a^T \otimes I,
$$
where $I$ denotes a size $n$ identity matrix and $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).